# Вирус в роутере через qr код

Tags: вирусы, qrcode

Суть дела такая просканировал qr код на роутере кинетик. Выкинуло на вредоностный сайт. Внимание не обратил . Зашел в настройки по ип 192.168...
подключил роутер к инету , после чего как я понимаю вирус прошивает мой роутер. И на роутер ростелеком вирус накатил прошивку кинетик причем кривую. И все конец. Сброс не работает ...

Comment: Жесткий сброс должен работать - посмотрите инструкцию к роутеру - возможно, нужно зажать сброс при выключенном питании и потом включать.

Comment: Причем весь интерес в том ,что если с данного айфона которым сканировали qr код настраивать любой роутер с 192.168.1.1  то вирус подхватывается если роутер выходит в инет

Comment: И на роутере Ростелеком и на роутере тенда появилась кривая прошивка? Которая убивает твой инет?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется в роутере стояла галочка автообновления прошивки. Новая синяя прошивка? Согласен - она не так удобна как "белая", надо привыкнуть. Проблем с работой роутера я не заметил.